# как строку превратить в словарь

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, словарь

Есть такой код

```
ast = '{"default-offer":{"isCutPrice":false,"isDSBS":false,"isDigital":false,"isBnpl":true,"isCredit":false},"skuId":"100590525029","offerId":"F_fu7ZtYnIRnY0Nm3U0OMg","price":14660,"oldPrice":16289,"productId":14265117,"wareId":"F_fu7ZtYnIRnY0Nm3U0OMg","feedId":475690,"shopId":431782,"supplierId":431782,"isExpress":false,"isAnyExpress":false,"shop_sku":"7217","isBnpl":true,"isCredit":false,"isInstallments":false,"warehouseId":98615,"businessId":696611,"isFoodtech":0,"hasBadgeNew":false,"hasBadgeExclusive":false,"hasBadgeRare":false,"promos":[],"brandName":"yandex-market","hasAddress":0,"showUid":"16573804368590675893100001"}'
atr = eval(ast)
```

Пробовал превратить строку в словарь  через eval, ошибку получаю из за того что false  и true c маленькой буквы, мне нужно каждый раз их с большой буквы написать, как я могу это сделать?
от этого словаря мне нужно только одно значение price, если я получу это значение не надо даже превращать в словарь

Comment: Попробуйте библиотеку json.

Comment: переменная ast случайно не requests получина?

Comment: @СергейШ спасибо большое

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import json

ast = '{"default-offer":{"isCutPrice":false,"isDSBS":false,"isDigital":false,"isBnpl":true,"isCredit":false},"skuId":"100590525029","offerId":"F_fu7ZtYnIRnY0Nm3U0OMg","price":14660,"oldPrice":16289,"productId":14265117,"wareId":"F_fu7ZtYnIRnY0Nm3U0OMg","feedId":475690,"shopId":431782,"supplierId":431782,"isExpress":false,"isAnyExpress":false,"shop_sku":"7217","isBnpl":true,"isCredit":false,"isInstallments":false,"warehouseId":98615,"businessId":696611,"isFoodtech":0,"hasBadgeNew":false,"hasBadgeExclusive":false,"hasBadgeRare":false,"promos":[],"brandName":"yandex-market","hasAddress":0,"showUid":"16573804368590675893100001"}'

atr = json.loads(ast)
print(atr['price'])

fcc = eval(ast.replace('true', 'True').replace('false', 'False'))
print(fcc['price'])
```